# A Column has been removed from a table SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

There has been an issue with one of the tables. The table has been altered and a column has been removed from the table.
There are 2 chances of this happening in the database according to my knowledge.

1. The code changes deployed by one of our colleague
2. Some one has manually altered the table.

I need to identify if there was an alter statement run during a particular time (Maybe with user information)

Comment: It is not going to help you now, but I have found the suggestions in [this article by Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/) very useful in tracking changes like this. So although not helpful now, it could well help you in the same situation in the future.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to glean who made the schema change from the default trace:

```
--query all default trace rollover files for schema modifications
SELECT  
     trace.DatabaseName
    ,trace.ObjectName
    ,te.name AS EventName
    ,tsv.subclass_name
    ,trace.EventClass
    ,trace.EventSubClass
    ,trace.StartTime
    ,trace.EndTime
    ,trace.NTDomainName
    ,trace.NTUserName
    ,trace.HostName
    ,trace.ApplicationName
    ,trace.Spid
FROM (SELECT REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(path), 1, CHARINDEX(N'\', REVERSE(path)), '')) + N'\Log.trc' AS path
    FROM sys.traces WHERE is_default = 1) AS default_trace_path
CROSS APPLY fn_trace_gettable(default_trace_path.path, DEFAULT) AS trace
JOIN sys.trace_events AS te ON 
    trace.EventClass=te.trace_event_id
JOIN sys.trace_subclass_values AS tsv ON
    tsv.trace_event_id = EventClass
    AND tsv.subclass_value = trace.EventSubClass
WHERE te.name = N'Object:Altered'
    AND tsv.subclass_name = 'Commit'
ORDER BY trace.StartTime;
```

Comment: How much old data is available using your above query?

Comment: @PareshJ, the default trace is a rollover trace with a maximum of 5 files of 20MB each, so up to 100MB data.  Run query `SELECT * FROM sys.traces WHERE is_default = 1;` to see these properties.

Comment: @DanGuzman:Thanks for the info on max size,does the trace last even after restart of server

Comment: Never mind ,i found here .http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48052/what-event-information-can-i-get-by-default-from-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You also can query database transaction log .,if your database is in Full Recovery model..

I deleted a table column and below are my test results..

```
create table t3
(
id int,
id1 int
)

alter table t3
drop column id1
```

Now when i query tlog i get below info..

```
select suser_sname([transaction sid]),operation,[transaction name],[begin time],[lock information],description
 from fn_dblog(null,null) where [lock information] like '%place object_id of table here%'


username            operation      transaction name   begin time             lock information                              description
somename            LOP_BEGIN_XACT  ALTER TABLE      2016/08/26 18:52:52:763    NULL                                       ALTER TABLE;0x0105000000000005150000008c052d5705824bfa733f63aedf280000
null                LOP_LOCK_XACT   NULL                  NULL                 ACQUIRE_LOCK_SCH_M OBJECT: 6:1922105888:0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see when the last modification of the table occurred. This should give you last change (within two weeks)

```
    SELECT 
    SO.Name
    ,SS.name 
    ,SO.type_desc 
    ,SO.create_date
    ,SO.modify_date 
 FROM sys.objects AS SO
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS SS 
    ON SS.schema_id = SO.schema_id 
WHERE DATEDIFF(D,modify_date, GETDATE()) < 14
AND TYPE IN ('P','U')
```